# Highlight static blog page link in header

Tags: posts, theme-development, themes, navigation

I created a navigation bar like tab system for my header and I can get all but my news button to highlight on that page.  The news is a static page for all of my blog/news post.

Not sure if it's my code but if anyone has any ideas, much thanks to you.

```
<?php
$parent_title = get_the_title($post->post_parent);
?>

            <?php
                $items = wp_get_nav_menu_items("main-nav");
                foreach($items as $item): 
            ?>
            <a <?php  if($item->title == $parent_title){ echo 'class="active '.$parent_title.'"';}else{ echo 'class="'.$item->title.'"';} ?> href="<?php echo $item->url; ?>"><?php echo $item->title; ?></a>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: Why are you outputting `wp_get_nav_menu_items()` directly, instead of calling `wp_nav_menu()` and using the core-generated CSS classes?

Comment: Because I wanted the freedom to customize the HTML and CSS of the menu.  I didn't want the generated html like: ul or li tags.  Plus it gives me freedom to set up my links the way I want them.

Comment: You can do **all of that** with the output from `wp_nav_menu()` (except for the generated `<ul>` and `<li>` tags of course - but then, those tags are *semantically* correct since you're outputting a *list*).

Comment: Could you show how I can go about this?

Comment: I've just posted an answer to do just that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per your comment:

> Because I wanted the freedom to customize the HTML and CSS of the menu. I didn't want the generated html like: ul or li tags. Plus it gives me freedom to set up my links the way I want them. – blackbull77 20 hours ago
>
> You can do **all of that** with the output from `wp_nav_menu()` (except for the generated `<ul>` and `<li>` tags of course - but then, those tags are *semantically* correct since you're outputting a *list*). – Chip Bennett 19 hours ago
>
> Could you show how I can go about this? – blackbull77 44 mins ago

1. Output your list via `wp_nav_menu()`, referencing the `theme_location`, like so:

   ```
   <?php
   wp_nav_menu( array(
       'theme_location' => 'primary_nav'
   ) );
   ?>
   ```
2. Target the `.current-menu-item` CSS class to style according to your needs
3. For the default fallback menu, you can also target the `.current_page_item` CSS class.
4. To style parent/ancestor menu items, target `.current-menu-parent`, `.current-menu-ancestor`, `.current_page_parent`, and `.current_page_ancestor`.
5. To add your own, custom CSS classes, use the [`nav_menu_css_class` filter](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu#Adding_Conditional_Classes_to_Menu_Items).

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer by accident and I'm going pass it on for anyone that may want to try this out.

Here's how I did it:

```
<?php if ( is_page() ) {

        $parent_title = get_the_title($posts_page->post_title);
        echo $parent_title;    

 } else {

    $posts_page_id = get_option( 'page_for_posts');
    $posts_page = get_page( $posts_page_id);
    $posts_page_title = $posts_page->post_title;

    $parent_title = $posts_page_title;
    echo $parent_title; 

 } ?>

 <?php
     $items = wp_get_nav_menu_items("main-nav");
     foreach($items as $item): 
  ?>
        <a <?php  if($item->title == $parent_title){ echo 'class="active '.$item->title.'"';}else{ echo 'class="'.$item->title.'"';} ?> href="<?php echo $item->url; ?>"><?php echo $item->title; ?></a>
 <?php endforeach; ?>
```

What it does is if the post is a page,  it will post the title of the parent page other wise it will give you the name of the blog static page title. Hope this help some people.

[Special Thanks to DynamicWP article!](http://www.dynamicwp.net/articles-and-tutorials/url-for-blog-page-when-using-static-omepage/)